# Best utility for converting Flip Mino HD videos to Windows Movie Maker compatible format?

Tags: video, conversion, mp4, windows-movie-maker, flip

I've got a Flip Mino HD and am looking for a free utility that will convert the default `mp4` video format into something that is Windows Movie Maker ([Live](http://download.live.com/moviemaker) or [Standard](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/updates/moviemaker2.mspx)) friendly.

What do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SUPER ©](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html)** (Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer) is right up to the task.

> Input Video format: 3gp, 3g2, amv,
>   asf, avi, dat, dvr-ms, fli, flc, flv,
>   m2ts, mpg, mkv, mov    m4v, **mp4**, nsv,
>   ogm, qt, rm(vb), str, swf, ts, trp,
>   ty, ty+, tmf, viv, vob, wmv ..

choose **WMV** as output format and you'll get a file you can then use with Windows Movie Maker.

*SUPER is freeware.*

Comment: Never actually worked with any of the videos on my Flip. "ERROR OCCURRED" every time regardless of the settings I've selected.

Comment: strange, i have no problems converting h.264 MP4. can you open and play the videos in SUPER?

Comment: I'll check this out as soon as I get a chance - I don't wanna leave your answer unaccepted, I've just not had time to revisit it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Another powerful Windows GUI video processor is called "MPEG Streamclip" --I use it to do exactly what you asked.