# windows movie maker imports .mp4 files as X's

Tags: windows, mp4, video-editing, windows-movie-maker

When I drag the .mp4 files from my video camera into movie maker, they all end up as X's with an error message about not understanding the format.  However, they play fine in Media Player.  Now what?

Comment: It's one thing being able to play the video, but quite another to decode it into a format for editing in Movie Maker. You will need *those* codecs.

Comment: How do I know which codecs and how to I get them?  Also, if I can play the video, doesn't that prove that I have the codecs already?

Answer (score 0):

Answered at [Best utility for converting Flip Mino HD videos to Windows Movie Maker compatible format?](https://superuser.com/questions/61098/best-utility-for-converting-flip-mino-hd-videos-to-windows-movie-maker-compatible/319627#319627) which suggested

[SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) © (Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer)

and

[MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/): video converter for Mac & Windows